# OCaml: Throw away return value in imperative code

Tags: ocaml, imperative-programming

How do I successfully throw away the return value of a function and treat it as if it's returning unit (for side-effects, obviously). The obvious approach is to do this:

```
let foo = begin
  some_ignored_thing ();
  actual_return
end
```

However, the compiler complains (with a warning) that the return type of `some_ignored_thing` isn't unit.

I could invent my own method, such as:

```
let ignore a = ()
```

Which seems at least concise and flags that something's going on, but is there anything in the language/stdlib that achieves the same thing? I'd have thought it would be a relatively common use case.

Comment: The `ignore` method is in language, as you defined it.

Comment: Gah! Typical. If you want to stick that as the answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I can recommend u to use
let (_:type) = some_ignored_result () in
to add type-checking to your code. It will be helpful if some_ignored_result is not your function and it can be changed after upgrading some library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, there is an `ignore : 'a -> unit` function that does exactly this.

The compiler actually knows about `ignore` and hard-code a specific behavior that is generally very useful, but can occasionally be inconvenient: by default, ignoring a function (anything with a type of the form `foo -> bar`) will raise a warning.

The reason for this is that forgetting to add the last argument of a function is a relatively common mistake. You may write for example

```
ignore (List.map (fun x -> foo bar))
```

while you meant to write

```
ignore (List.map (fun x -> foo bar) li)
```

and the effects you expect to see applied are not.

So `ignore` will raise a warning in this case, which your hand-coded `let ignore x = ()` does not do. People also sometimes write

```
let _ = foo in ...
```

to ignore `foo`, but this suffer from the same downside (it's easy to be wrong about what the type actually is). Kakadu recommends to use a type annotation there, and that's a reasonable advice.

(Some people also use `let _ = ...` for the "main" expression of their program. I recommend to rather use `let () = ...` for this same reason that it forces more type precision.)

Finally, some people prefer to use the `let _ = ...` form because they are in situations where using `;` would force them to add parentheses or `begin..end`. I recommend that you always add parentheses or `begin..end` in these cases, because it's easy to shoot yourself in the foot with that -- obscure precedence rules for `if..then..else..` for example.

Comment: Nit: Why would anybody in their sane mind ever write ``ignore (List.map (fun x -> e) l)`` instead of ``List.iter (fun x -> ignore e) l``?

Comment: Come on, it was an example.

Comment: I wondered the same thing when writing this example, yet was too lazy to pick a better one. Yet I seemed to thinly remember that I had in fact encountered this situation before. So either it was with another type that had a `map` but no `iter` in the standard library, or there is a worse justification: the mapping function was already defined as a value (rather than a function literal), and in absence of a composition operator in the standard library (a sad, but realistic assumption), it's in fact (slightly) more convenient to `ignore (map f li)` than to `iter (ignore . f) li`. Dubious.

Comment: Not from the memory usage standpoint. you're better of with the `iter` version. Unless there would be a reason for allocating values on purpose, just to ignore the final result?